# Generate Certificate x5c from a JWT in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jwt, x509certificate, x509

I am trying to create a x5c from a JWT, I have the public key.  Every time I try "generateCertificate" I always get an error.

```
static String Getx5cValue() {
    try {
 

        def certificateData = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" + // This has five - before and after         
        "TU[Loads of other test]Cg\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" // This has five - before and after
        certificateData = certificateData.trim()
        
        System.out.println(" Convert the certificate string to a byte array")
        def certificateBytes = certificateData.getBytes();

        System.out.println(" Create a ByteArrayInputStream to read from the byte array")
        def byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateBytes);
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621414/reading-an-x-509-certificate-with-java

        System.out.println("  getInstance( X.509 ")
        def certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        Certificate certificate
        while (byteArrayInputStream.available() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Im in a while loop")
            // https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html
            // The next line will throw an error
            // java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: extra data at the end
            certificate  = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(byteArrayInputStream);
            System.out.println(certificate.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("  Iterate through the certificates and print them")
        Iterator<? extends Certificate> iterator = certificate.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Certificate cert = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(cert);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" e.getMessage() " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I get given the following error.  I have cut the code up, removed and added /n to the certificateData, trimmed it, removed the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE.   I seem to keep getting the following error.

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: extra data at the end
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:186)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:105)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:355)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:321)
    at Main.Getx5cValue(Main.groovy:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:321)
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:19)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:287)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:393)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:382)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:649)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:389)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.access$1400(GroovyMain.java:67)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain$GroovyCommand.process(GroovyMain.java:313)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:141)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: extra data at the end
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:428)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:340)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:183)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798809/how-to-generate-jwk-from-a-x-509-pem-certificate-in-jose4j) to use classes that deal correctly with certificate formats.